# Laravel pusher not authenticated in Localhost but authenticated in Development Server

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification, pusher

I have just setup my Laravel notification with pusher in private channel. Everything is working fine on Development Server(127.0.0.1:8000). I have received notification regularly ,but when I tried to run from localhost(http://localhost/) getting authentication error "http://localhost/broadcasting/auth 404 not found". Here is my code:

**Reportnotification.php**

```
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'message'=>$this->details,
        'link'=> $this->link,
    ];
}

public function toBroadcast($notifiable): BroadcastMessage
{
    return new BroadcastMessage([
        'message' => "$this->details",
        'link'=> "$this->link"
    ]);
}
```

**Events/ReportNotification**

```
class ReportNotification implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    // public $username;
    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {

        $message = $this->message;
 

   }

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
  
 return new PrivateChannel('notification');
}
```

**Listeners/SendReportNotification**

```
public function handle($event)
{
    $admins = User::where('role',1)->get();
    ReportNotification::send($admins, new ReportNotification($event->user));
}
```

**Channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('App.Models.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
```

});

**master.blade.php**

```
<script>
        var id = {{Auth::user()->id}}
        Echo.private('App.Models.User.'+id)
        .notification((ReportNotification) => {
            console.log(ReportNotification.message);
            console.log(ReportNotification.link);
        });

    </script>
```

These are my codes. Everything working properly in **"127.0.0.1:8000"** but not working in **"localhost"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `localhost` name normally resolves `127.0.0.1`.

When you open `http://localhost`, it resolves `127.0.0.1:80` because `80` is the default port number for HTTP protocol.

Your server is listening to `8000` as you said. So you should try `localhost:8000` instead or change the port that your webserver uses to `80`.